# ¿Cómo usar una función de python desde html?

Tags: html, python, django

Estoy comenzando a usar python y quiero hacer un input en html con el cual cargue un archivo txt para procesarlo en python.

Este es mi input

```html
<button 
  class="input-group-text" 
  type="submit" 
  action="problema1Python/index.py/readDocument"
  method="post">
    iniciar
</button>
```

Quiero que mi función de python reciba el archivo txt para procesarlo:

```py
    def readDocument(fileTXT):
        print(fileTXT)
        f = open ('./problema1Python/mensaje.txt','r')
        mensaje = f.read()
        print(mensaje)
        f.close()
```

Agradecería su ayuda.
O en su defecto me pueden decir si hay alguna mejor alternativa pára hacer esto

Comment: Una sugerencia es que pongas como etiqueta el framework que usas ya sea Django, Flask u otro, esto para que obtengas la ayuda que necesitas

Comment: Justo agregue el framework Django ya que no conocia esta parte es mi primer acercamiento a python

Comment: Ok, ponlo como etiqueta, para que así llame la atención de otros que sepan de esto, lastimosamente yo no podré ayudarte ya que no se mucho de Django

Comment: Creo que el problema no esta relacionado con python, si no con una confusión en cuanto a como se crean las aplicaciones Web. Generalmente python no es utilizado para la ejecución de código en el lado del cliente (a menos que estes utilizando Brython o algo por el estilo), en su lugar se usa javascript que es el encargado de comunicarse con una aplicación en el lado del servidor que puede estar escrita en python, te recomiendo estudiar sobre frontend(css, js, html, etc) y después checar backend con python y algún framework como Django, esto te va dar una visión más certera sobre donde estas.

Comment: Bueno, también podría utilizar el _vetusto_ [Grail](http://grail.sourceforge.net/) como navegador con el que puede usar python en el lado cliente o, mucho mejor, la implementación python [Pyodide](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide) para webassembly que funcionará en cualquier navegador moderno. Pero mejor no abrir esos melones.

Comment: Justo comencé a estudiar sobre esto y modificare mi pregunta para hacer mas funcional esto